# Forgot GCP email, Have Oauth Client Id, Client Secret, Project Id, Developer Key,

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, clientid

After Cleaning  my system and re-installing chrome, I realized that only my primary google account and password data was saved, and can not remember the email address I used for my GCP login.  I have found some Oauth information used, including project Id, Client Id, Client secret, Dev Key, and certs.  Is there a way to utilize those pieces of information to retrieve the email address associated with that GCP account?

Comment: So you had 2 different google accounts, one your personal and the other for GCP ? if that's the case there's no way to go back to the second one with the info you specified. I think you also have the project ID, you could try ask support for the owner of that project, but you have to verify ownership somehow, not sure they are gonna reply to that if you are not an enterprise.

Comment: I just had an idea, if by any chance you performed gcloud auth application-default login with that account you might have that information in your system. Check for a file called application_default_credentials.json inside cloud sdk folder.

Comment: Yes, you are correct,I have multiple accounts. I can verify the billing information (ie.  cc number and my name) associated with the GCP account, I am now curious to see if there is a way I can recover the credentials based on payment method.

Comment: I have not downloaded the cloud SDK...  I primarily use GCP for sql, and API's.  I will download and attempt it, and touch back in a few...

Comment: The sdk was able to authenticate, however, the only email address listed is the  "api-channel@[project].iam.gserviceaccount.com address.  Maybe I can add an additional user and role to the project..

Comment: if you had it installed before on your machine maybe it was worth the shoot, I'm sorry no way to go back with that method if you just installed it :(

Comment: Do you have any support plans https://cloud.google.com/support/#support-plans activated for your account? You can try to contact GCP support and provide them your financial history and other details as a proof.

Comment: I highly doubt that contacting Google Cloud Support will be helpfull in this case because

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Google Cloud Support calling the phone 1-855-817-0841, this could be the easiest way to get help in this case. If you have a support role you may be able to demonstrate that you are the owner of the project and in this way get some help with this.

Another alternative is using any other account authorized in your project. If you added another member of your team as editor i.e. he can access and see the authorized accounts through the IAM menu.